# I can't debug/make my app crash. OTOH Crashlytics iOS reports some crashes in-field for some users: NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: ios, objective-c, debugging, crashlytics

I've been coding my typical random stuff in Objective-C/iOS for some years.

Today, a customer I'm dealing with came up with this apparently innocent Crashlytics crash:

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException 
0  CoreFoundation 0x193b0e1c0 \__exceptionPreprocess 
1  libobjc.A.dylib 0x19254855c objc_exception_throw 
2  CoreFoundation 0x193b15278 \__methodDescriptionForSelector 
3  CoreFoundation 0x193b12278 \___forwarding___ 
4  CoreFoundation 0x193a0c59c _CF_forwarding_prep_0 
5  MyProjectTargetName 0x100087518 -[BannerContainer pressed:] (BannerContainer.m:105)
6  UIKit 0x199f3059c -[UIGestureRecognizerTarget _sendActionWithGestureRecognizer:] 
7  UIKit 0x199f33ca4 _UIGestureRecognizerSendTargetActions 
8  UIKit 0x199af52e8 _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions 
9  UIKit 0x199993828 -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:buttonEvent:] 
10 UIKit 0x199f23ce8 _UIGestureEnvironmentUpdate
...
```

The thing is, in line 105, inside of BannerContainer.m "Bannercontainer pressed:" IBAction, there's an apparently easy assignation:

```
if(self.banners==nil || [self.banners count]==0)
    {
        return;
    }

    NSInteger position=self.currentPosition; // both NSIntegers

    if(IS_IPAD) // Macro working perfectly as of today
    {
        position=((UIButton *)sender).tag;  // this is offending line 105
    }
```

According to Crahslytics, the NSInvalidArgumentException is crashing in line 105... But I can't identify any "invalid argument" there. Instead I would say it's just a button and its (NSInteger) tag attribute being assigned onto a NSInteger variable (sender is ALWAYS a button, as this function is linked to 5 UIButtons inside the .xib file). These 5 buttons have 5 different tags (0, 1, 2, 3 and 4 ). if sender is nil, that line doesn't even crash (I manually set sender to nil to check this claim 5 minutes ago).

Whatever, the thing is I've never been able to make my app crash ON THIS line, as apparently crashlytics says some people in-field have been able to do.

I'm somehow clueless. Any hint? Any rubber-duck debugging someone can guide me through? Why Crashlytics is able to find a crash condition I can't find in my development environement?

Greetings.

EDIT: I don't have access to that Crashlytics account. This crash I posted is just a .txt dump my customer sent us via email. I don't have nor access to this app production environment servers neither to my customer itunes connect account. I just deliver my code to my customer, and then he compiles, signs and uploads everything with his accounts.

Comment: @Issac Are you sure that always sender is an UIButton?

Comment: this IBAction is only linked to 5 UIButtons inside a xib. I can't see how/why sender should not be a UIButton. My problem is I can't make this line crash (!!) and I would like to (as apparently Crashlytics says sometimes can)

Comment: Can you check if sender is UIButton and then make the assignation?, this must fix your crash, and if is not a UIButton then send a crashlytics error, to check what is going on

Comment: I don't have a crash, that's my problem. I would really like to have one on my developement machine, but the crash is only appearing in the production version of the product, in-field, inside the Crashlytics account of my customer (account I can't access, he only gives me this .txt dump I posted above).

Comment: Yes @Isaac, I know you can't reproduce the crash but, you can work in what you think that is the problem cause or you do nothing about it, the decision is up to you my friend

Comment: Yes, I understand I can put an "if" before the UIButton.tag assignation, but I can't say my customer: "I think I've fixed something", without having checked really if I actually have fixed it, because for me it's not crashing. "I need to make it crash". As a test, I've typed "sender = [[UIColor alloc] init]; ", just above the tag assignation and then it crashes, but with a "unrecognized selector", instead of Crashlytics "NSInvalidArgumentException"...

Comment: you can test if you have some UIGestureRecognizer with this action as target, check the line before the crash is calling [UIGestureRecognizerTarget _sendActionWithGestureRecognizer:] and then crashes on [BannerContainer pressed:], maybe there is the problem, please let me know

Comment: Does the crash occur consistently on the devices where it occurs? Can you tell whether the crashes occur on specific device types and/or iOS versions?

Comment: According to the log, the `sender` is a UIGestureRecognizer — not a button.

Answer (score 0):

Problem "solved" (Can't say for sure though!!).

Well, as was expectable from debug, sender seemed not to be an UIButton.
Apparently, when my app crashed under crashlytics it was because sender was actually a "UITapGestureRecognizer" (as some of you have pointed and was deductable from debug).

But more things had happened also: my customer sent me better info about his crashlytics crash.txt dump, that is, he told me additional info appearing in some other lines of his Crashlytics web interface, these lines made me review other code parts of my app (It was some code written by another person in the past) and that lead me to the correct conflicting lines.

Reviewing these new code parts and files I finally discovered someone was registering tap gestures "on top of my buttons" (to say it somehow) somewhere else in the life cycle of that controller. These gestures were assigned the same "pressed button" IBAction function than I had linked for my real buttons in IB.

This makes sense in the iPhone version of my app (where we don't have buttons, but views, so we need to capture gestures on top of them), but overlaps with ipad version of my app (the crashlytics crashing one), which DOES have buttons to capture clicks.

So, to solve this situation I just removed the selector registering lines for tap gestures, and no more tap gestures get registered when this controller initializes (all this in ipad mode).

Starting from today, Crashlytics shouldn't crash anymore because of this, but I will only know it for sure in some weeks, once this version gets published.

And still, I haven't been able to make this piece of faulty code crash with my own hands, so my worry is still not 100% eased. I'm more than sure I've solved it, but I don't feel total victory.

Greetings and thanks for your help and analysis.